# List Search is not working in sharepoint online using post Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I have one list in SharePoint online.

All the columns of list are mapped to crawled properties. 
Still I am not able to retrieve any data from list using search.

It is working fine on one of my site. But it's not working on other site.

On Edit page --> Add web part - - > Search Category is missing, is this the reason why its not working?